# free CDN to store my images and css files for django on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I am learning to deploy `django` apps on `heroku`.From the articles on  heroku site and many posts on SO ,I learned that `Amazon S3` is a popular choice for `CDN`. I know this may sound quite strange to most of the readers.. Unfortunately I don't have a credit card (because of where I live and my bank acct status etc --long story :() and cannot sign up for Amazon S3. IS there any free file hosting site which I can use as `MEDIA_URL` or such?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site for locating free hosting, advice on hosting services, or any other vendor recommendations. It's a site for specific programming and programmers tools related questions. Google and Bing are excellent sources for finding things, and they both do a pretty good job of searching and returning links to the results they find. Voting to close as off-topic. Good luck.

Comment: sorry ..I was trying to find if anyone was in a similar situation and how they solved it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/), they have a [CDN feature](http://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn) and a [free plan](http://www.cloudflare.com/plans).

Comment: it seems that you need a top level domain (say www.damon.com) for using cloudflare.so something like  http://mountaingoat1234.herokuapp.com which is a free app on heroku is not supported

Answer (score 1):

depending on your scale Google AppEngine might be the best solution.

you can sign up without a credit card and if you build a simple project to host and serve your static assets as long as you stay under the free daily limits (for storage size and bandwidth) their infrastructure is pretty robust.